# Unexpected stringstream behavior

Tags: c++, iostream, stringstream, istream

Consider the following code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream ss;

    ss << string("12");
    int h;
    ss >> h;
    cout << h << endl;

    ss.str(string("")); // clear the content of ss

    ss << string("30");
    int m;
    ss >> m;
    cout << m << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running the above code yields some random output:

```
12
0
```

At some other times, the following output is observed:

```
12
4
```

I expected the output to be simply:

```
12 
30
```

Why did I get the unexpected results?

Also, what should be the best way to parse a `string s` to `int i` without necessary C++11 support? Should it be `int i = atoi(s.c_str())`?

Comment: _'Also, what should be the best way to parse ...'_ Use `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Your not clearing out the stream appropiately, use `ss.clear()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you extract `12` from the stream, you reach the end of it, which puts it in a bad state. Any further extractions will fail. You need to call [`ss.clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) around the time you clear its contents.

If you had checked the success of your extractions, you would have avoided this problem. I generally expect to see any extraction from a stream as some kind of condition.

And yes, using string streams to parse strings as integers is a perfectly reasonable way to do it pre-C++11. I would prefer it over using `atoi`. For anybody who wants to know the C++11 way, use [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Thanks! What should be the best way to parse a `string s` to `int i`? Is `stringstream` a good idea?

Comment: @lwxted Yeah, I'd prefer to see that over `atoi`.

Comment: @lwxted Using `istringstream s("123"); s >> value` or `ostringstream s; s << value; s.str()` should avoid the problem in the question (avoid stringstream).

Comment: @lwxted, `std::stoi(str)`

Answer (score 0):

For those who're here with something similar to the above but not exactly, I found that when you've got a stream in a scenario where you need to re-use it (like in a while loop), the easiest way to avoid head-aches (in addition to `ss.clear`) is to create a new stream each time. For example:

```
int GetInteger(){
    cout << "Enter an int: " << endl;
    string userInput;
    while (true){
        stringstream ss;
        getline(cin,userInput);
        ss << userInput;
        //Making sure that an int was passed
        int result;
        if (ss >> result){
            //Making sure that there is no extra stuff after
            string extra;
            if (ss >> extra){
                cout << "Unexpected stuff at end of input: " << extra << endl;
            } else{
                return result;
            }
        } else {
            cout << "Number you entered is not an INT. Please enter an integer" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Retry: " << endl;
        // ss.clear();
    }
}
```

So every time the user enters an invalid input, at the start of the while loop, I create a new stringstream object. While researching my function's undefined behavior, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506146/why-stringstream-has-this-behavior) question that has a similar example.