# Why stringstream has this behavior?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have a code like this, concerning stringstream. I found a strange behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int     p, q;
  fstream file;
  string  str;
  stringstream sstr;

  file.open("file.txt", ios::in);
  if(file.is_open()) {
    while(getline(file, str)) {
      sstr << str;
      sstr >> p >> q;
      cout << p << ' ' << q << endl;
      sstr.str("");
    }
  }
  file.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Suppose I have file.txt as

```
4 5

0 2
```

with return after `5` in the first line and 2 in the second line.  The program gives me:

```
4 5

4 5
```

which means `p` and `q` are not correctly assigned. But I checked that each time `sstr.str()` with get the correct string of the line.

Why stringstream has a behaviour like this?

Comment: What's the expected output instead?

Comment: Does [How to clear stringstream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848087/how-to-clear-stringstream) solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

The stream is in a non-good state after reading the second integer, so you have to reset its error state before resuming.

Your real mistake was to not check the return value of the input operations, or you would have caught this immediately!

---

The simpler solution may be to not try to reuse the same stream, but instead make it anew each round:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (!(iss >> p >> q >> std::ws) || !iss.eof())
    {
        // parse error!
        continue;
    }
    std::cout << "Input: [" << p << ", " << q << "]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read `p`, then `q`, you reach the end of your stream and the flag `eofbit` is set and you can't do anything anymore.
Just `clear()` it and your code will work as you expect.

But you may want to use directly `file` instead, and `file.close();` will have a better place within your `if`:

```
fstream file;
file.open("file.txt", ios::in);
if(file.is_open()) {
  int p, q;
  while(file >> p >> q) {
    cout << p << ' ' << q << endl;
  }
  file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some redundant lines: `fstream` could be opened during the definition and no explicit file `close()` is needed, as it is automatically destroyed at the end of `main()`.

Additionally, in your file reading loop, the line: `sstr << str` should be replaced with `stringstream sstr(line);` if you want to initialize a new `stringstream` for each line, which will make the line: `sstr.str("");` redundant as well.

Applying the above corrections, here is your code:

```
int main() {

   int p, q;
   fstream file("file.txt", ios::in);

   // check status
   if (!file) cerr << "Can't open input file!\n"; 

   string line;

   // read all the lines in the file
   while(getline(file, line)) {

       // initialize the stringstream with line
       stringstream sstr(line);

       // extract line contents (see Note)
       while (sstr >> p >> q) { 

           // print extracted integers to standard output
           cout <<"p: " << p <<" q: "<< q << endl;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

---

Note: The line `while (sstr >> p >> q)` assumes that a line contains only integers, separated by white space.